# VSTS query to show which tasks are assigned to me in active stories

Tags: azure-devops

We have recently swapped to Kanban style swim lanes for managing our backlog of user stories. When I look down the user stories in development I can see clearly who each story is assigned to. But I cannot, at a glance, tell if I am assigned any of the tasks within that story without opening the task:

[image: My task in Martin's story]

How do I make a VSTS query that will show me the tasks assigned to me within stories that are currently active (but not necessarily assigned to me)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. I can use a [direct links query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/using-queries) to list the active user stories with thier tasks that are assigned to me.

[image: Query editor screen shot]